# what is the correct use of schema.org imageGallery

Tags: google-schemas

i tried to make use of schema.org for an image gallery but the images are not indexed by google

link is [link to azie4y](http://www.azie4y.nl/Sri-Lanka/Nuwara-Eliya.html)!
are there any examples on the web apart from the schema.org webpage ? for example the imageObject

Answer (score 0):

Having a structured web site is required for the indexing process but is not the only thing needed. Here ( https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/70897?hl=en) you can find more information about how the process works, good practices and tools like https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769 to help your website being indexed.
Hope this information helps.